# Create multiple comparisons without packages

Tags: r

I would like to create multiple comparisons using a programming approach in R. This in a complete factorial design as when I use the gen.factorial () function AlgDesign package. Could someone tell me how from my code I could create it, since I can not use the gen.factorial () function directly because in my real data I have unbalanced data.

## Factor

```
treat <- gl(4, 15, labels = paste("t", 1:4, sep="")); treat
```

## Variables

```
set.sed(125)
sp  <- cbind(c(rnorm(10,  5, 0.25), rnorm(50, 2.5, 0.25)), rnorm(60, 2.5, 0.25),
             c(rnorm(10, 12, 0.25), rnorm(50, 2.5, 0.25)), rnorm(60, 2.5, 0.25))
colnames(sp) <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4")
```

## Comparisons

```
TI    <- model.matrix(~ treat-1)
head(TI)

f <- nlevels(treat)
comb <- t(combn(1:f, 2))
n    <- nrow(comb)

contr2 <- NULL
for (x in 1:n) {
      i <- comb[x, 1]
      j <- comb[x, 2]
      tmp <- list(TI[,i] - TI[,j]); names(tmp) <- paste0("TI",i, "_", j)
       contr2 <- c(contr2, tmp) }
contr2df <- as.data.frame(contr2)
contr2df# OK  but incomplete
```

## Equivalent, but creating a full factorial design

```
require(AlgDesign)
contr2df2 <-AlgDesign::gen.factorial(3, 6, TRUE, varNames=c("TI1_2", "TI1_3", "TI1_4", "TI2_3", "TI2_4", "TI3_4"))
contr2df2
```

#

Thanks,
Alexandre

Comment: Personally, your question is unclear.

Comment: Alex I would like to transform contr2df in contr2df2 output using contr2 function.

Comment: Please provide your expected output